# How to change seek bar values from 0 to 5 using Robotium in Android

Tags: android, robotium

I have a seekbar, while moving it I want to change values from 0 to 5. I have a TextView, where I display those values while moving the seekbar. 
I tried using the following code but it just shows that the seekbar is progressed but it doesn't update the values of the progressed seek bar.

```
int yourProgress = 3;

ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) solo.getView(R.id.sbQuestionMarks);
pb.setProgress(yourProgress);
```

somebody give me a hint or an example how to do this in Robotium automation?

Comment: Have you used solo.setProgressBar()?

Comment: Thanks I tried this the progress bar is incremented but the value of the incremented progress bar is not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have one SeekBar you can use `solo.setProgressBar(0, 5);`. Where 5 is your progress. It works for me for standard android [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html)

Comment: This works for standard android SeekBar what if the SeekBar is customized? is there any other way

Comment: If it doesn't work for your SeekNar let's look at your custom implementation. Can you provide it here?

Comment: hi got my problem fixed actually i had a TextView which had to be updated after the seek bar is progressed.